# Cannot allocate memory Failed to allocate when using KenLM build_binary

Tags: c++, nlp, n-gram, language-model, kenlm

I have a `arpa` file which I created by the following command:

```
 ./lmplz -o 4 -S 1G <tmp_100M.txt >100m.arpa
```

Now I want to convert this `arpa` file to binary file:

```
./build_binary 100m.arpa 100m.bin
```

And I'm getting error:

```
mmap.cc:225 in void util::HugeMalloc(std::size_t, bool, util::scoped_memory&) threw ErrnoException because `!to.get()'.
Cannot allocate memory Failed to allocate 106122412848 bytes Byte: 80
ERROR
```

I tried to add `-S` parameter:

```
./build_binary -S 1G 100m.arpa 100m.bin
```

and I got the same error.

1. How can I convert to binary file ?
2. Why I'm getting this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://aclanthology.org/W16-4618 for some light explanation

Try this instead:

```
LM_ORDER=4
CORPUS_LM="tmp_100M"
LANG_E="txt"
LM_ARPA="100m.arpa"
LM_FILE="100m.bin"

${MOSES_BIN_DIR}/lmplz --order ${LM_ORDER} -S 80% -T /tmp \
< ${CORPUS_LM}.${LANG_E} | gzip > ${LM_ARPA}

${MOSES_BIN_DIR}/build_binary trie -a 22 -b 8 -q 8 ${LM_ARPA} ${LM_FILE}
```

`MOSES_BIN_DIR` is the directory where the binaries you've compiled are stored.

---

If you still face the memory issue when using the trie and quantization options, you might need to change to a machine/instance where the CPU RAM is sufficient to read your language model and produce the binary.